# Will there be any diffraction if the gap width is smaller than the wavelength?

Tags: optics, waves, diffraction, wavelength

As the diffraction will be the largest when the wavelength is equal to the gap width, I wondered if there would be any diffraction if the gap width is smaller than the wavelength, and If there is, why won't it be larger than when the gap length and wavelength are equal?

Comment: Where did you get that the diffraction is largest when the gap is equal to the wavelength?  And what does it mean? Largest in what sense?

Answer (score 1):

In the limit to small slit width the light is uniformly diffracted over all angles.